# C++: Duda con getline()

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo C++ y en el libro que estoy leyendo explica (un poco encima) por como usar la función getline(), así que escribí este código para probarlo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

main ()
{
   string prueba;
   getline(cin, prueba, ",");
   cout << prueba;
}
```

El problema es que me tira este error el build messages (estoy usando Code:Blocks como IDE y MinGw como compilador):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'getline((std:istream&, std::__cxxll::string&,...
```

(El error esta en la línea 9)

Comment: ¿Qué intentas hacer con el `getline`?
Para leer una variable (en este caso de tipo `string`) haces `cin >>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El *prototipo* es muy claro

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& getline( 
    std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input, 
    std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str,
   CharT delim
);
```

Fíjate en el primer argumento de la plantilla ( el último argumento de la función: ) **`charT`** (que, para `std::string`, es un **`char`**; tú, sin embargo, estas usando un **`char *`**.

Cambia tu código a

```
getline( cin, prueba, ',' );
//                    ^
```

Observa el cambio: las *comillas dobles* (`"` ) por **comillas simples** ( `'` ).